# Поддержка протокола mailto

Tags: javascript, email, протоколы

#### Описание

Добавил на странице кнопку "поддержка": нажимаешь — открывает письмо адресованный мне...
Функционал простой, использую протокол mailto:

```js
buttonShare.addEventListener(`click`, (event) => {
    const addressee = `eccs0103@gmail.com`;
    const subject = `Subject`;
    const message = `Message`;
    location.href = `mailto:${addressee}?subject=${encodeURIComponent(subject)}&body=${encodeURIComponent(message)}`;
});
```

#### Проблема

Так вот при наличии почтового клиента браузер открывает его, но при его отсутствии не происходит ничего.

#### Вопрос

Неловко получается, когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку и ничего не происходит. **Как могу я понять — открылась ли почтовый клиент или нет, чтобы хотя бы сообщение соответствующее показать.**

---

#### Дополнительно 1

Посмотрел множество сайтов. Тот же SO на английском. Конкретного ответа нигде нет. Может тут найдется.

#### Дополнительно 2

[Взгляните](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/ho2M/nK7FAfuDj) как все это выглядит.

Comment: `mailto:` существует десятки лет - очень сомневаюсь, что его кто-то не поддерживает. Может проблема в том, что ты вместо нормального `encodeURIComponent` используешь мусорный `encodeURI` и ещё `location.assign` вместо ссылки?

Comment: @Qwertiy вот беру текст `mailto:eccs0103@gmail.com` и вставляю в адресную строку в Edge на ПК. Происходит перезагрузка и... ничего. Браузер просто  молчит. У меня Outlook реагирует на этот протокол. Но я его не использую и он выключен, а сам браузер ничего не делает, ничего не открывет.

Comment: А какой результат вы ожидали от браузера? ``mailto`` открывает почтовый клиент.

Comment: @Neverm1ndo Так вот. Если нету почтового клиента, ничего не происходит. Как мне понять открылось что-то, или нет?

Comment: Это похоже на то, что вы ищете? [Detecting web-based mail client vs local mail client for a mailto link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837370/detecting-web-based-mail-client-vs-local-mail-client-for-a-mailto-link)

Comment: @eccs0103, так надо не в адресную строку вставлять, а в ссылку.

Comment: @Neverm1ndo это не полноценное решение, но с этим можно поэкспериментировать.

Comment: @Neverm1ndo, у меня ощущение, что этот код запросто запустит почтовую программу просто для проверки... Такой сайт живо отправится в чёрный список.

Comment: @eccs0103 нашел кое-что на SO, но это костыль: [Is there a way to detect if the browser has a mailto protocol handler set?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69951588/6468198)

Comment: @AndreiKhotko думаю это то что предложил пользователь **Neverm1ndo** вот [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1537333/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0-mailto?noredirect=1#comment2763972_1537333)

Comment: Я бы предложил отправлять форму на бэк, и с бэка уже отправлять по smtp письмо по адресу, чем искать костыли для ``mailto``.

Comment: @eccs0103 вам нужно получить настройки клиента, судя по видео, которое вы записали? если да, то почему просто на нажатие кнопки не отправить этот объект настроек на сервер, а сервер бы отправил вам эти настройки по почте и сделал бы еще что-нибудь полезное (сохранил в бд, например)?. Или вам важно знать, от кого вы получили настройки?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko мне неважно от кого настройки, но код работает не на сервере. Это скорее локальный проект, который работает для каждого устройства отдельно.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что такие ссылки надо помещать не в адресную строку, а в ссылки:

```
var subject = "Subject"
var message = "Message"

var a = document.createElement('a')
a.href = `mailto:eccs0103@gmail.com?subject=${encodeURIComponent(subject)}&body=${encodeURIComponent(message)}`
document.body.appendChild(a)
a.click()
```

Впрочем, не уверен, что параметры работают...

PS: Без сниппета потому что в нём всё равно работать не будет из-за настроек безопасности айфрейма.

Comment: [Результат](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3i8ht.png) не отличается. Копируется элемент `a`, но в основном без изменений.

Comment: @eccs0103, у меня работает: запускается почтовая программа windows.

Comment: Да. Если бы она у меня была, наверно, запустилось бы. Но если у меня / у пользователя отсутствует эта программа, то не происходит ничего. И это выглядит странно. И при этом я не получаю никакой отклик, что "ничего не произошло", чтобы показать сообщение.

Comment: Попробую снимать видео. Думаю будет понятнее.

Comment: @eccs0103, вот тут что настроено? https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6IIz.png Вот оно и должно открываться.

Comment: Понимаю. Но если там ничего не настроено, то ничего не происходит. Получается пользователь нажал и ничего не произошло. А я как разработчик должен уведомить его, что "у тебя программы нету, поэтому не произошло ничего". Только вот как мне узнать - у него произошло открытие программы или нет? Проще говоря, [смотрите](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/ho2M/nK7FAfuDj).

Comment: @eccs0103, ну да, логично. Кстати, вариант с присваиванием ссылки лучше, чем с созданием и кликом. Не уверен6, что тут можно проверить. Вообще, такую отправку почты очень редко используют.

Comment: @eccs0103, если у пользователя не указан почтовый клиент по-умолчанию, то система предложит выбрать, какой клиент использовать. Думаю, что пользователь догадается, что в списке, который возможно будет пуст, нет подходящей программы.

Comment: @Neverm1ndo как вы можете увидеть в показанном мною видео мне ничего не предложили. И я как пользователь скорее бы думал, что проблема в странице, а не у меня.

Comment: @Qwertiy [Какие-то фокусы делал](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlCpQ.png) чтобы хоть что-то произошло. )) Но это скорее костыль, чем решение.